# Perl Data Cleaning : how can I do a list of unduplicated names et store all these little lists in an hash?

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, if-statement, hash

I am a beginner on Perl and I have to do some data cleaning. 
Just to sump up quickly what I am doing
I have a list of ID (Horse_ID), each ID is for one horse. The Horses competed in several races, that's why their ID is printed on several lines (so each line matches with one competition). For each race they competed with a different trainer (or not).

[Original data to show exactly with what I am dealing with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsUsa.png)

I would like to store in an hash the names of the different trainers for each horses, and the number of the different trainers each horse have.

After have consulted some post on stack overflow, I built a code. But my code prints only the first name of the trainer found and the wrong number of trainers (0 sometimes which doesn't mean anything). I can't find the mistake... This is my code :

```
if (($coach =~ /\w+/) && ($Horse_ID ne '')) { 
    if (($trainerhash -> {$Horse_ID} -> {trainerinfo}) && ($trainerhash -> {$Horse_ID} -> {trainerinfo} !~ /$Horse_ID/)) {
        $trainerhash -> {$Horse_ID} -> {trainerinfo} .= "\t$coach"; 
        my @coach = split (/\s/, $coach);
         $numtrainers = $#coach+1;

    }
    elsif (!$trainerhash -> {$Horse_ID} -> {trainerinfo}) {
        $trainerhash -> {$Horse_ID} -> {trainerinfo} = "$coach";
    }

}

# Trainer hash - Number of trainers & trainer names
$trainerhash -> {$Horse_ID} -> {trainerinfo} = "$numtrainers\t$coach";
```

If someone have an idea, it would be great... I have already tried with a for loop but the result is the same.

Input data

```
Horse_ID    name    date    localisation    distance race_kategory  rider   rider_weight    coach
1   Abakus  03/11/2018  Warszawa    1400    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  6
1   Abakus  09/09/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  5
1   Abakus  12/08/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   A_Kabarov   58  S_Vasyutov  x
1   Abakus  30/06/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  8
1   Abakus  09/06/2018  Warszawa    1600    II  V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  1
2   Abbas   19/11/2017  Warszawa    2000    I   S_Vasyutov  58  S_Vasyutov  3
2   Abbas   28/10/2017  Warszawa    1400    II  P_Naoniechnyi   58  S_Vasyutov x
2   Abbas   08/10/2017  Warszawa    1400    II  P_Naoniechnyi   58  S_Vasyutov x
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input data and desired output. Cut and paste your input data for a separate block as you did with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are great for finding duplicates or grouping items. We're going to use them for grouping horses and removing duplicate trainers.

The number of trainers is simply the numbers of elements in the array of trainers, so we don't need to store the number anywhere.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my %trainers_by_horse;
if (defined( $_ = <DATA> )) {
   chomp;
   my @headers = split /\t/;
   while (<DATA>) {
      chomp;
      my %fields;
      @fields{@headers} = split /\t/;
      my $horse_id = $fields{Horse_ID};
      my $trainer  = $fields{coach};
      ++$trainers_by_horse{$horse_id}{$trainer};
   }
}

# Convert from
#    $trainers_by_horse{$horse_id}{$trainer} = $num_rows;
# to
#    $trainers_by_horse{$horse_id} = \@trainers;

for my $trainers (values(%trainers_by_horse)) {
   $trainers = [ sort keys(%$trainers) ];
}

for my $horse_id (sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%trainers_by_horse)) {
   my $trainers     = $trainers_by_horse{$horse_id};
   my $num_trainers = @$trainers;

   say(join("\t", $horse_id, $num_trainers, join(",", @$trainers)));
}
```

(I assumed your data was tab-separated. If it's merely whitespace separated, just remove both `/\t/`.)

For example,

```
Horse_ID    name    date    localisation    distance    race_kategory   rider   rider_weight    coach
1   Abakus  03/11/2018  Warszawa    1400    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  6
1   Abakus  09/09/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  5
1   Abakus  12/08/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   A_Kabarov   58  S_Vasyutov  x
1   Abakus  30/06/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  8
1   Abakus  09/06/2018  Warszawa    1600    II  V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  1
2   Abbas   19/11/2017  Warszawa    2000    I   S_Vasyutov  58  S_Vasyutov  3
2   Abbas   28/10/2017  Warszawa    1400    II  P_Naoniechnyi   58  S_Vasyutov  x
2   Abbas   08/10/2017  Warszawa    1400    II  P_Naoniechnyi   58  S_Vasyutov  x
2   Abbas   30/07/2017  Warszawa    1800    II  P_Naoniechnyi   58  S_Vasyutov  x
3   Abdank  19/05/2018  Warszawa    1600    II  S_Vasyutov  58  S_Vasyutov  3
4   Adlina  07/09/2008  Wrocaw  1700    II  D_Szope 56  J_Pochwatka 9
4   Adlina  07/09/2008  Wrocaw  1800    II  D_Szope 58  S_Vasyutov  6
```

produces

```
1   1   S_Vasyutov
2   1   S_Vasyutov
3   1   S_Vasyutov
4   2   J_Pochwatka,S_Vasyutov
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211463/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-perl-data-cleaning-how-can-i-do-a-list-of-undu).

Answer (score -2):

Please see the code snippet how

> input is read
>
> split into fields
>
> stored in `%race` hash
>
> formed `%trainer` hash with information of interest
>
> output `%trainer` hash data (no desired output format offered by OP)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my($header,@fields);
my %trainer;

$header = <DATA>;
chomp $header;

@fields = split ' ', $header;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    next if /^$/;           # skip empty lines
    my %race;
    @race{@fields} = split;
    push @{ $trainer{$race{Horse_ID}}{trainerinfo} }, $race{coach} 
        if not grep { /$race{coach}/ } @{ $trainer{$race{Horse_ID}}{trainerinfo} };
}

say Dumper(\%trainer) if $debug;

say '
Horse   Count   Trainers
----------------------------';
for ( sort keys %trainer ) {
    printf "%d\t%d\t%s\n",
            $_, 
            scalar @{$trainer{$_}{trainerinfo}},
            join(', ', @{$trainer{$_}{trainerinfo}});
}

__DATA__
Horse_ID    name    date    localisation    distance race_kategory  rider   rider_weight    coach
1   Abakus  03/11/2018  Warszawa    1400    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  6
1   Abakus  09/09/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  5
1   Abakus  12/08/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   A_Kabarov   58  S_Vasyutov  x
1   Abakus  30/06/2018  Warszawa    1800    I   V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  8
1   Abakus  09/06/2018  Warszawa    1600    II  V_Popov 58  S_Vasyutov  1
2   Abbas   19/11/2017  Warszawa    2000    I   S_Vasyutov  58  S_Vasyutov  3
2   Abbas   28/10/2017  Warszawa    1400    II  P_Naoniechnyi   58  S_Vasyutov x
2   Abbas   08/10/2017  Warszawa    1400    II  P_Naoniechnyi   58  S_Vasyutov x
2   Abbas   30/07/2017  Warszawa    1800    II  P_Naoniechnyi   58  S_Vasyutov x
3   Abdank  19/05/2018  Warszawa    1600    II  S_Vasyutov  58  S_Vasyutov  3
4   Adlina  07/09/2008  Wrocaw  1700    II  D_Szope 56  J_Pochwatka 9
4   Adlina  07/09/2008  Wrocaw  1800    II  D_Szope 58  S_Vasyutov  6
```

Output

```
Horse   Count   Trainers
----------------------------
1       1       S_Vasyutov
2       1       S_Vasyutov
3       1       S_Vasyutov
4       2       J_Pochwatka, S_Vasyutov
```

NOTE:

- consider to name hash `%horse` to keep list of coaches/trainers for a horse
- consider to name hash `%trainer` to keep list of trained horses by a coach

Comment: This code also suffers from a code injection bug, and it assumes that Erica and Eric are the same name. `/$race{coach}/` should be `/^\Q$race{coach}\E\z/` or just `$_  eq $race{coach}`

Comment: Tip: `/^\s*\z/` would be safer than `/^$/`

Comment: @ikegami -- yes, it would warranty that no lines with spaces without data. Ideally input data should not have such lines. Picture with input data provided by OP did not had such lines -- included for demonstration purpose only.

Comment: @ikegami -- please demonstrate how _code injection bug_ will manifest itself with provided data. I would like to see it (with present data at hand and not assumed for bad case scenario).

Comment: @ikegami -- I sad not assumed for bad case scenario! If I had such data then I would write _comparison_ differently. If you build a small electronic circuits -- do you get it certified with all certification agencies of the world? I don't think so -- because it does not make any sense and cost a lot of money. Same here -- it is code sample not intended for production code and should not work for any possible case. If it would be so then a lot of perl documentation will require a serious re-work.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your answers! I have actually 300 horses and I just provided a sample. So @ikegami the code works well except for some horses  : for example the horse n°295 has 1 trainers but it says 2 . Please see my data sample below, do you have any ideas of where this  comes from ?

Comment: @Rima -- you mention data sample but no any link is provided. You can upload your data file to some public service and provide a link to it.

Comment: oh yes sorry, well I finally solved my problem, thank you all for your help!!